# Unable to print 3x3 Matrix and the sum of each line that is called by 2 functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the objective for the following code below: 
    Write a program so that main calls the following functions:
    getMatrix – creates and returns a 3 x 3 matrix.

printMatrix – prints the matrix row by row without showing brackets

sumRow – returns the sum of the elements of a single row of the matrix (pass in the matrix and the row index)

**Issue I am having**: After further research I am unable to figure out why I am unable to compute the sum for each matrix line. Moreover, I am trying to print the matrix without brackets. Spent a couple days trying to figure this out myself? I am sure it is a silly error that I cant seem to figure out. Does the for loop have to be in main?

```
def main():
    compute = getMatrix()
    showMatrix(compute)
    getSum(compute)

def getMatrix():
    matrix = []  #Create an empty array

    numberOfRows = eval(input("Enter the number of rows: "))  
    numberOfColumns = eval(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
    print( 'Creating',numberOfRows,'x',numberOfColumns, 'Matrix in progress..')
    for row in range(numberOfRows):
        matrix.append([])
        for column in range(numberOfColumns):
            value = eval(input("Enter the element for {} : ".format(column)))
            matrix[row].append(value)
return matrix

def showMatrix(matrix):
    print("\n")
    for newLine in matrix:
        print(newLine)

def getSum(matrix):
    for row in range(len(matrix[0])):
        total = 0
        for column in range(len(matrix)):
            total += matrix[row][column]
            print("Sum for matrix", row, "is", total)
    return total

main()
```

using 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 as testing

Comment: Be careful with your code indentation (e.g. : first return, your show matrix function, your second return)

Comment: Does this code match your code exactly as it appears in the original source file, indentation and all? Because I'd expect this program to print nothing at all, instead crashing immediately with `IndentationError: unexpected indent` on the `for column in range(numberOfColumns):` line.

Comment: @Kevin It does not. When I run it I can create and get the 3x3 matrix to print; however, it does not compute and show sum of each Row of the matrix. I used some of the edits here, but it shows the sum after each element has been entered. I only need it to compute sum of each row.

Comment: Ok, well, go ahead and [edit] your post so that it _does_ exactly match the code you're running.

Comment: @Kevin The code is now updated. – TheFryeGuy

Answer (score 0):

To print without bracket:

```
def showMatrix(matrix):
    print
    for newLine in matrix:
        for elem in newLine:
            print elem,
        print
```

Change `total += matrix[num][column]` to `total += matrix[row][column]`to fix your getSum problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we would get back to the beginning, lets consider you have following matrix

```
a = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
```

To print and get row sums of matrix you may use next functions

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for column in row:
            print column,

        print

def row_sum(matrix):
    return map(sum, matrix)

>>> print_matrix(a)
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
>>> row_sum(a)
[6, 15, 24]
```